# How to upload app to TestFlight for sandbox User?

Tags: testing, app-store-connect, testflight

I have already created sandbox tester account.

I want to upload TestFlight app for sandbox User only including developer certification not production certificate, is it possible?

if yes than how?

any reference link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

`TestFlight` builds are production builds. If you need to distribute the app through `TestFlight`, you **must** need to have production certificate and provisioning profile to build and submit.